# How to change Flowable Logo on Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring, workflow, flowable, workflow-engine

I’m using Java Spring boot and added maven dependencies of Flowable. Is there any way to customize Flowable logo on admin panel from spring application by overriding the logo? If there is any example, that would be good.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find your answer in [here](https://documentation.flowable.com/latest/develop/fe/user-themes/#logo-and-favicon-images)

Comment: Is this only for enterprise edition?

Comment: I don't think so.